# Extracting a 2 x 2 matrix from a 9 x 9 matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 9, i = i + 8,
  For[j = 1, j <= 9, j = j + 8,
    Print[k[[i, j]]]
  ]
]
```

The code prints a column of the elements that I want to extract, but
I want them as a 2 x 2 matrix. How can I modify my program so it does that?

I want to use For-loops to form the 2 x 2 matrix.

Comment: It is not quite clear what exactly you are asking for, but I am quite positive that `Table` and `Do` will help you.

Comment: `k[[{1,9},{1,9}]]` might also do it (look up `Part`). Note that `Print` just prints and does not create a new matrix.

Comment: i knw but can i not make any changing in my code to print a matrix form

Comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrived test data.

```
m1 = Array[k, {9, 9}]
```

> ```
> {{k[1, 1], k[1, 2], k[1, 3], k[1, 4], k[1, 5], k[1, 6], k[1, 7], k[1, 8], k[1, 9]}, 
>  ... 
>  {k[9, 1], k[9, 2], k[9, 3], k[9, 4], k[9, 5], k[9, 6], k[9, 7], k[9, 8], k[9, 9]}}
> ```

Here is how to solve your problem with For-loops. `m2` will be the matrix you want. You can substitute any 9 x 9 matrix for `m1` and the code will still work.

```
m2 = ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}];
For[i = 1; ii = 1, i <= 9, i += 8; ii += 1,
  For[j = 1; jj = 1, j <= 9, j += 8; jj += 1,
    m2[[ii, jj]] = m1[[i, j]]]];
m2 // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

But really, wouldn't it be simpler just to write

```
m2 = {m1[[1, 1]], m1[[1, 9]], m1[[9, 1]], m1[[9, 9]]}
```

or

```
m2 = {m1[[1, 1]], m1[[1, -1]], m1[[-1, 1]], m1[[-1, -1]]}
```

or perhaps

```
m2 = Extract[m1, Tuples[{1, 9}, 2]]
```

or

```
m2 = Extract[m1, Tuples[{1, -1}, 2]]
```

Comment: ...or `m1[[{1, 9}, {1, 9}]]`..

Comment: ... or `m1[[1;;9;;8,1;;9;;8]]`...

Comment: @halirutan . Sure, but Henrik already mentioned that one in a comment.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. Yeah, that, too. There are probably more.

Comment: Waht i do with your code if i want to extract 4*4 matrix  just like that                       ConstantArray[0, {4, 4}];
For[i = 1; ii = 1, i <= 9, i += 8; ii += 1,
  For[j = 1; jj = 1, j <= 9, j += 8; jj += 1,
   For[k = 3; kk = 3, k <= 11, k + 8; kk + 1,
    For[l = 3; ll = 3, l <= 11, l + 8; ll + 1,
     m2[[ii, jj, kk, ll]] = m[[i, j, k, l]]]]]];
m2 // MatrixForm

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to achieve this. The solution differs based on what one wants exactly. If the element's positions are combinations of *m* and *n* in the list, the crude way of achieving this is:

```
Table[t[[i,j]],{i,{m,n}},{j,{m,n}}]
```

In the above, t is the list that contains the elements. This will generate the list of the elements required. As the output is required in the matrix form,

```
Table[t[[i,j]],{i,{m,n}},{j,{m,n}}]//MatrixForm
```

will print the list in the matrix form.

**Update:**
Let A is the list that contains the extracted elements, B is the identity matrix that has to be added and m and n are the elements in the indices

```
A=Table[t[[i,j]],{i,{m,n}},{j,{m,n}}] (*extracts the elements from the list t from the postions, {m,m},{m,n},{n,m} and {n,n}*)
B=IdentityMatrix[2];  (*generates identity matrix of size 2*)
C=A+B;   (*compltes addition of lists and stores in C *)
Print[MatrixForm[C]]  (*Prints C in the matrix form*)
```

Comment: thanks sirr but a want a changing in for loop to create matrix .. any idea

Comment: Actually i have to evaluate a fomulla  for different values so i need as input matrix

Comment: If you want it to be used in subsequent parts of the code, this can be stored as another variable and can be used.

Unless it is clearly stated what exactly wanted, it is difficult to help with the code!

Comment: okk sirr problem is that i extract elements using above code appear like a columns  but i want to make 2*2 matrix because i have to add these elments with identity matrix.. i think you will b clrear now

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in [`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) and something similar to [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) then

```
With[{prnt = WriteString[$Output, ##] &},
 For[i = 1, i <= 9, i = i + 8,
  For[j = 1, j <= 9, j = j + 8,
   prnt[k[[i, j]], " "]
   ];
  prnt["\n"]
  ]
 ]
```

From the documentation *details* for [Print](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html)

> With a text-based interface, Print ends its output with a single
>   newline (line feed).
>
> Print sends its output to the channel $Output.

And each `Print` will be in an independent cell, but we can [`WriteString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html) to the same [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Output.html) using

```
WriteString[$Output, #] &
```